# how can i solve dio https status 401 error?

Tags: java, flutter, api, dart, flutter-layout

```
I/flutter (16411): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401]
I/flutter (16411): #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
I/flutter (16411): #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
I/flutter (16411): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16411): #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
I/flutter (16411): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: have you tried using any API testing tool ?

Comment: 401 means Unauthorized. You need to make sure, how to make this API `authorized`. Such as add some token to the header or whatever.

Comment: I have added token as Dio().options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token"; but also it reflects same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add token to api headers like the following:

```
  Map<String, String> _headers = <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };

makeRequest(){
_headers['access_token'] = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.get(url,
          options: Options(
            headers: _headers,
          )));
}
```

Notice that the key may not be "access_token" it depends on the backend